# codeigniter uri segment not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Ajax function -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
        url: base_url+'movies/index/this_week/hindi',
        type: "POST",
        success: function( data )
        {               
        $("#news1").html(data);
        }                 
     });
});
```

In my movies controller, when i print `$this->uri->segment(2)` or `$this->uri->segment(3)` in _remap() function it always return random value. Sometimes it returns index for both statements or sometimes it returns 'index' and 'hindi' etc.

All the time when i refresh the page, it returns random value. I am getting confused. Why it occurs?

Here is _remap() function.

```
function _remap()
{
    $segment_1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
    echo "1==>".$this->uri->segment(1);
    echo " 2==>".$this->uri->segment(2);
    echo " 3==>".$this->uri->segment(3);
    echo " 4==>".$this->uri->segment(4);

    switch ($segment_1) {
        case null:
              case false:
              case '':
                     $this->index();
                     break;

              case 'movies':
                    if($this->uri->segment(2) == "index" && $this->uri->segment(3) == "this_week")
                   {
                            $this->moviedescription($this->uri->segment(4));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                         $this->moviedescription();
                   }
                   break;

            default:
                    $this->index();
            break;
            }
        }
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting both segments to display?

Comment: where did you defined `base_url` var?

Comment: base_url is getting the correctly. Actually uri->segment() not returns the correct value in the _remap() function of movies controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code in my computer and it works perfectly. So, the problem is not in the code if `base_url` is  defined correctly in JAVASCRIPT. **Double check that.**

You may have set other routes in routes config file which is messing with the url or you may have problem with `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me at right direction. Problem is solved, I think, in .htaccess file one rule for the movies clashes with the routes in config file.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better approach than using uri segments. Try using function parameters, like this:

Your `movies` controller:

```
public function index($when = false, $type = false) { 
    ...
    echo $when, ', ', $type;
    // $when should be this_week and $type should be hindi, in your example)
    // $when isn't the best variable name, but you get the idea
}
```

And then just access those parameters normally as variables as they will always be the same, no random values. I've set their default values to false just in case you don't use them all the time (for example, if you have the default `movies` page).

Comment: Giving a +1 for the right way of doing things, even though you did not answer the askers real question. Kudos to you.

Comment: Thank you, and you see, it turned out that .htaccess was misconfigured, and it wasn't even mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 0):

it should not give you random values, that realy wierd and don't now for sure.

when you make your ajax request (from your example) to the controller, the reveiving controller should have:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1); // result "movies"
echo $this->uri->segment(2); // result "index"
echo $this->uri->segment(3); // result "this_week"
echo $this->uri->segment(4); // result "hindi"
```

you could pass an second param for the default value.

```
var_dump($this->uri->segment(5,FALSE)); // result BOOL FALSE
```